# Using custom membership provider users as Umbraco content editors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, umbraco

I am building a new MVC website with security managed by a default membership provider. The site will use Umbraco 7 for its structure and a certain amount of content editing but the core of the site will be a bespoke ASP.NET MVC application with its own users and business rules around user accounts.

Umbraco has its own membership provider. Certain users in my site will also be content editors in Umbraco, but I don't want them to have to login to Umbraco separately. Is this possible? I should point out I don't want to use Umbraco to manage the bulk of my site's users who will have nothing to do with content editing.

I've read a lot about extending the UmbracoDefaultProvider, but this always presupposes that all user accounts are being managed by the Umbraco back office.

Any guidance appreciated.

**Edit:**

Having analysed this a bit further (I'm still pretty new to Umbraco) I'm asking if it's possible to link member types with user roles, so an authenticated member can access the Umbraco back office and edit content. In my proposed system I'll have people who have a role in the main website (Umbraco 'members') who will also be responsible for content editing (Umbraco 'users'). Seems silly that they have to log in separately for each of these responsibilities but from research it seems to be impossible. Would be grateful if anybody could confirm.

Answer (score 0):

As Umbraco has it's own UI for managing the contents, its so unlikely to provide a separate place for some users that they want to change the contents as well.
You can develop a custom control panel interact with Umbraco separately for specific types of users but its just a duplication of some features of Umbraco backoffice.